# I want to make my Searchview similar to this

Tags: android, searchview

I have a searchview as show in the photo like the second one, I want to make it like the first one but I don't know how

[image]

Comment: What actually you want? Grey underline? Grey CloseButton?

Comment: no, the blue underline.

Answer (score 0):

1 First create Edit text and image view in horizontal layout.

2 Make Image view Visible false. There will be 2 images true_image and false_image,Based on the edit text value change image view image.

3 Method for Edit text is below:

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

 @Override
 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 Value = edittext.getText().toString();

   if(Your Condition){
      imageview.setimage(R.Drawable.true_image);
   }else{
       imageview.setimage(R.Drawable.false_image);
   }

 }

 @Override
 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
 int after) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 @Override
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }
 });
 }
```

Hope this answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize default search view with this code

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.xyz, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    if (searchItem != null) {

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

        if (searchView != null) {

            // Full view of search
            View searchPlate = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_plate);

            // Apply customisation as you want
            ImageView searchClose =(ImageView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);

            // Edittext of search view so you can customize this also
            EditText searchSourceText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);  
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change underline color:

```
View searchplate =searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_plate);
    searchplate.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```